# Getting InputStream with RestTemplate

Tags: java, inputstream, resttemplate

I am using URL class to read an InputStream from it. Is there any way I can use RestTemplate for this?

```
InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName()));
```

How can I get `InputStream`  with `RestTemplate` instead of using `URL`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should not get the `InputStream` directly. `RestTemplate` is meant to encapsulate processing the response (and request) content. Its strength is handling all the IO and handing you a ready-to-go Java object.

One of `RestTemplate`'s original authors, Brian Clozel, has [stated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21424#issuecomment-453472592):

> `RestTemplate` is not meant to stream the response body; its contract
> doesn't allow it, and it's been around for so long that changing such
> a basic part of its behavior cannot be done without disrupting many
> applications.

You'll need to register appropriate [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) objects. Those will have access to the response's `InputStream`, through an [`HttpInputMessage`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpInputMessage.html) object.

[As Abdull suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39417120/438154), Spring does come with an `HttpMessageConverter` implementation for `Resource` which itself wraps an `InputStream`, [`ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.html). It doesn't support all `Resource` types, but since you should be programming to interfaces anyway, you should just use the superinterface `Resource`.

The current implementation (4.3.5), will return a [`ByteArrayResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html) with the content of the response stream copied to a new `ByteArrayInputStream` which you can access.

You don't have to close the stream. The `RestTemplate` takes care of that for you. (This is unfortunate if you try to use a [`InputStreamResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html), another type supported by the `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`, because it wraps the underlying response's `InputStream` but is closed before it can be exposed to your client code.)

Comment: "You should not get the InputStream directly. RestTemplate is meant to encapsulate processing the response (and request) content. Its strength is handling all the IO and handing you a ready-to-go Java object." Absolutely wrong. In some cases serialized object is much larger than the heap can contain, and due to that you **must** stream its serialization rather than convert it into string or what ever serialized medium you use and only then write it out into your buffer into output stream.

Comment: @Dragas You're not wrong about `InputStream` in general. However, `RestTemplate` was not designed to support that streaming use case. You can see that [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21424#issuecomment-453472592) from one of its original authors' (Brian Clozel) comments: _`RestTemplate` is not meant to stream the response body; its contract doesn't allow it, and it's been around for so long that changing such a basic part of its behavior cannot be done without disrupting many applications._

Answer (score 58):

The previous answers are not wrong, but they don't go into the depth that I like to see. There are cases when dealing with low level `InputStream` is not only desirable, but necessary, the most common example being streaming a large file from source (some web server) to destination (a database). If you try to use a `ByteArrayInputStream`, you will be, not so surprisingly, greeted with `OutOfMemoryError`. Yes, you can roll your own HTTP client code, but you'll have to deal with erroneous response codes, response converters etc. If you are already using Spring, looking to `RestTemplate` is a natural choice.

As of this writing, `spring-web:5.0.2.RELEASE` has a `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` that has a `boolean supportsReadStreaming`, which if set, and the response type is `InputStreamResource`,  returns `InputStreamResource`; otherwise it returns a `ByteArrayResource`. So clearly, you're not the only one that asked for streaming support.

However, there is a problem: `RestTemplate` closes the response soon after the `HttpMessageConverter` runs. Thus, even if you asked for `InputStreamResource`, and got it, it's no good, because the response stream has been closed. I think this is a  design flaw that they overlooked; it should've been dependent on the response type. So unfortunately, for reading, you must consume the response fully; you can't pass it around if using `RestTemplate`.

Writing is no problem though. If you want to stream an `InputStream`, `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` will do it for you. Under the hood, it uses `org.springframework.util.StreamUtils` to write 4096 bytes at a time from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`.

Some of the `HttpMessageConverter` support all media types, so depending on your requirement, you may have to remove the default ones from `RestTemplate`, and set the ones you need, being mindful of their relative ordering.

Last but not the least, implementations of `ClientHttpRequestFactory` has a `boolean bufferRequestBody` that you can, and should, set to `false` if you are uploading a large stream. Otherwise, you know, `OutOfMemoryError`. As of this writing, `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` (JDK client) and `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` (Apache HTTP client) support this feature, but not `OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory`. Again, design oversight.

**Edit**:
Filed ticket [SPR-16885](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16885).

Comment: @Kieveli I’m not sure what you mean by no example. I provided references to practical use cases like streaming. Spoon feeding code isn’t the goal of this answer.

Comment: Not sure it's a design flaw. I think it's just the result of the design decision to have RestTemplate manage the resources within the call. I hit this same issue when I tried to use an InputStream I retrieved in JdbcTemplate. It had closed the result set and thus the input stream to the CLOB field. But great explanation.

Comment: `bufferRequestBody` should be considered only when sending file via post or put. If we talk about reading InputStream from http response, it can be ignored

Answer (score 49):

Spring has a `org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter`. It converts Spring's `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` class.
That `Resource` class encapsulates a `InputStream`, which you can obtain via `someResource.getInputStream()`.

Putting this all together, you can actually get an `InputStream` via `RestTemplate` out-of-the-box by specifying `Resource.class` as your `RestTemplate` invocation's response type.

Here is an example using one of `RestTemplate`'s `exchange(..)` methods:

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange( someUrlString, HttpMethod.GET, someHttpEntity, Resource.class );

InputStream responseInputStream;
try {
    responseInputStream = responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

// use responseInputStream
```

Comment: `responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream();` is incorrect. there is no getInputStream method.

Comment: @brainstorm, versions older and newer than `spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE` have a [`org.springframework.core.io.Resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) which extends `org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource` which provides `getInputStream()`

Comment: The underlying InputStream will be a be ByteArrayStream. This means the response body will be loaded into memory.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It obviously load everything into memory. The above response is therefore not correct.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same issue and solved it by extending RestTemplate and closing the connection only after the stream is read.

you can see the code here: https://github.com/ItamarBenjamin/stream-rest-template

Comment: Can you please add license to your repository on GitHub? I wanted to use it in my project, but I cannot according to this: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license

Comment: sure @afrish. as i've never done that, can you let me know what exactly do i need to add there? when i uploaded it my intention was that anybody who needs it would use it. glad to see you found it helpful.

Comment: I think you can follow this https://docs.github.com/en/communities/setting-up-your-project-for-healthy-contributions/adding-a-license-to-a-repository and choose MIT or Apache license there

Answer (score 6):

Very simple, yet efficient solution would be using `ResponseExtractor`. It's especially useful when you want to operate on very large InputStream and your RAM is limited.

Here is how you should be implementing it:

```
public void consumerInputStreamWithoutBuffering(String url, Consumer<InputStream> streamConsumer) throws IOException {

    final ResponseExtractor responseExtractor =
            (ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) -> {
                streamConsumer.accept(clientHttpResponse.getBody());
                return null;
            };

    restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, responseExtractor);
}
```

And then, invoke the method anywhere you need:

```
Consumer<InputStream> doWhileDownloading = inputStream -> {
                //Use inputStream for your business logic...
};

consumerInputStreamWithoutBuffering("https://localhost.com/download", doWhileDownloading);
```

Please, be aware of the following **common pitfall**:

```
public InputStream getInputStreamFromResponse(String url) throws IOException {

    final ResponseExtractor<InputStream> responseExtractor =
            clientHttpResponse -> clientHttpResponse.getBody();

    return restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, responseExtractor);
}
```

Here `InputStream` will be closed before you can access it

Answer (score 5):

I solve it by doing that.
I hope it will help you all.

```java
    @GetMapping("largeFile")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadLargeFile(
            @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName
    ) throws IOException {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // Optional Accept header
        RequestCallback requestCallback = request -> request.getHeaders()
                .setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL));

        // Streams the response instead of loading it all in memory
        ResponseExtractor<InputStreamResource> responseExtractor = response -> {
            // Here I write the response to a file but do what you like
            Path path = Paths.get("tmp/" + fileName);
            Files.copy(response.getBody(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            return new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(String.format("tmp/%s", fileName)));
        };

        InputStreamResource response = restTemplate.execute(
            String.format("http://%s:%s/file/largeFileRestTemplate?fileName=%s", host, "9091", fileName),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            requestCallback,
            responseExtractor
        );

        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, String.format("attachment; filename=%s", fileName))
            .body(response);
    }
```

Comment: when request body is handled by a message converter it will be ByteArrayInputStream at the end and it will load in-memory, your example does'nt solve core problem, you are not loading in-momory while creating request that is good part.

Comment: @DVSingh, thank for sharing. I don’t say what your commented is wrong. I’ve used and well test on the code I posted. It’s actually solved the problem.

Comment: it's loaded to into the memory, but it doesn't mean the whole capacity. it's loaded piece by piece of bytes through the stream.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Abhijit Sarkar's answer for leading the way.

I needed to download a heavy JSON stream and break it into small streamable manageable pieces of data.
The JSON is composed of objects that have big properties: such big properties can be serialized to a file, and thus removed from the unmarshalled JSON object.

Another use case is to download a JSON stream object by object, process it like a map/reduce algorythm and produce a single output without having to load the whole stream in memory.

Yet another use case is to read a big JSON file and only pick a few objects based on a condition, while unmarshalling to Plain Old Java Objects.

Here is an example: we'd like to stream a very huge JSON file that is an array, and we'd like to retrieve only the first object in the array.

Given this big file on a server, available at http://example.org/testings.json :

```
[
    { "property1": "value1", "property2": "value2", "property3": "value3" },
    { "property1": "value1", "property2": "value2", "property3": "value3" },
    ... 1446481 objects => a file of 104 MB => take quite long to download...
]
```

Each row of this JSON array can be parsed as this object:

```
@lombok.Data
public class Testing {
    String property1;
    String property2;
    String property3;
}
```

You need this class make the parsing code reusable:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import java.io.IOException;
@FunctionalInterface
public interface JsonStreamer<R> {
    /**
     * Parse the given JSON stream, process it, and optionally return an object.<br>
     * The returned object can represent a downsized parsed version of the stream, or the result of a map/reduce processing, or null...
     *
     * @param jsonParser the parser to use while streaming JSON for processing
     * @return the optional result of the process (can be {@link Void} if processing returns nothing)
     * @throws IOException on streaming problem (you are also strongly encouraged to throw HttpMessageNotReadableException on parsing error)
     */
    R stream(JsonParser jsonParser) throws IOException;
}
```

And this class to parse:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
public class StreamingHttpMessageConverter<R> implements HttpMessageConverter<R> {

    private final JsonFactory factory;
    private final JsonStreamer<R> jsonStreamer;

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return false; // We only support reading from an InputStream
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    public R read(Class<? extends R> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = inputMessage.getBody();
             JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(inputStream)) {
            return jsonStreamer.stream(parser);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(R result, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Then, here is the code to use to stream the HTTP response, parse the JSON array and return only the first unmarshalled object:

```
// You should @Autowire these:
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();

// If detectRequestFactory true (default): HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory will be used and it will consume the entire HTTP response, even if we close the stream early
// If detectRequestFactory false: SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory will be used and it will close the connection as soon as we ask it to

RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.detectRequestFactory(false).messageConverters(
    new StreamingHttpMessageConverter<>(jsonFactory, jsonParser -> {

        // While you use a low-level JsonParser to not load everything in memory at once,
        // you can still profit from smaller object mapping with the ObjectMapper
        if (!jsonParser.isClosed() && jsonParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            if (!jsonParser.isClosed() && jsonParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                return objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, Testing.class);
            }
        }
        return null;

    })
).build();

final Testing firstTesting = restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.org/testings.json", Testing.class);
log.debug("First testing object: {}", firstTesting);
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is able to process the whole file if you wanted to? The response stream is closed as soon as you exit the `try` block, so it appears that you will get an exception.

Comment: That's why the whole parsing is done before the end of the try block. When creating a new StreamingHttpMessageConverter<>(jsonFactory, jsonStreamer), the JsonStreamer lambda passed as second parameter will be used in the read(...) method: the whole JsonStreamer.stream(...) method/lambda will be called inside the try, while the stream is open. And yes, as soon as we end the try/read(), the stream is closed (when detectRequestFactory=false).

Comment: I see; I missed the fact that you’re returning `R`, so obviously you’ll have to consume the stream fully and deserialize into `R`

Comment: How to iterate through all the objects

Answer (score 4):

You can pass in your own response extractor. Here is an example where I write out the json to disk in a streaming fashion -

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().basicAuthentication("user", "their_password" ).build();

        int responseSize = restTemplate.execute(uri,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            (ClientHttpRequest requestCallback) -> {
                requestCallback.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                requestCallback.getBody().write(body.getBytes());
            },
            responseExtractor -> {
                FileOutputStream fos  = new FileOutputStream(new File("out.json"));
                return StreamUtils.copy(responseExtractor.getBody(), fos);
            }
    )
```

Comment: This actually works quite well.

If you're trying to stream a response from one service to another, you can copy this stream to your HttpServletResponse, or copy it to a file like you mentioned and then work with it as a local file

Answer (score -1):

As a variant you can consume response as bytes and than convert to stream

```
byte data[] = restTemplate.execute(link, HttpMethod.GET, null, new BinaryFileExtractor());
return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
```

Extractor is

```
public class BinaryFileExtractor implements ResponseExtractor<byte[]> {

  @Override
  public byte[] extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    return ByteStreams.toByteArray(response.getBody());
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what they are trying not to do.   If you read it in as a byte[] you are loading the whole thing in memory.   i.e. not a stream.    If you then stream it through after loading the whole thing in RAM you have the worst of both options.