# Transferring big files in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl

The spring integration flow I wrote has to get files (some of them are as big as 4G) from a rest service and transfer them to a remote shared drive. For downloading them from the rest service I configured this simple component:

```
@Bean
public HttpRequestExecutingMessagehandler httpDownloader (RestTemplate template){
  Expression expr = (new SpelExpressionParser()).parseExpression("payload.url");
  HttpRequestExecutingMessagehandler  handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessagehandler (expr, template);
  handler.setExpectedResponseType(byte[].class);
  handler.setHttpMethod(GET);
  return handler;
}
```

Unfortunately this won't scale meaning for larger files it will eventually throw `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, even if i add more memory with `-Xmx` or `-XXMaxPermSize`

So my question is, what to do in order to avoid these problems no matter how big the files will be?

Comment: you should have the bean that have big memories? I think that is too much. you can transfer the file using ftp in java

Answer (score 1):

I think I have answered you in some other similar your question that Spring `RestTemplate` is not designed for streaming response body. It is explained in this SO thread: [Getting InputStream with RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379835/getting-inputstream-with-resttemplate).

One of the solution which may work for your is to write a custom `HttpMessageConverter` which would return a `File` object containing data from HTTP response. [This article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file) explains how to do that with the `ResponseExtractor`, but something like `FileHttpMessageConverter` is not so hard to implement based on experience from that article. See `StreamUtils.copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out)`

Then you inject this `FileHttpMessageConverter` into your `HttpRequestExecutingMessagehandler` - `setMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters)`.

Your service for remote shared drive should already deal with this local temporary file to get that large content without consuming memory.

See also this one about possible approach via `WebFlux`: https://www.amitph.com/spring-webclient-large-file-download/

Comment: thank you! already did the first CustomFileConverter solution but hoped there's something better with direct streams...

Comment: You can do streaming only if you use `RestTemplate.execute()` directly and perform a transfer to the shared dir from its `ResponseExtractor`. It is just not possible to do HTTP streaming in Spring Integration since the `RestTemplate` closes an `InputStream` before returning to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Created this starting from `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` class and injected it into the custom RestTemplate I use. But this solution is based on using a `File` message, which is not quite the streaming I was hoping for.

```
public class FileCustomConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<File> {

    public FileCustomConverter() {
        super(new MediaType[]{MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.ALL});
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return File.class == clazz;
    }

    public File readInternal(Class<? extends File> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
        File outputFile = File.createTempFile(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), ".tmp");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        StreamUtils.copy(inputMessage.getBody(), outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        return outputFile;
    }

    protected Long getContentLength(File bytes, @Nullable MediaType contentType) {
        return bytes.length();
    }

    protected void writeInternal(File file, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        StreamUtils.copy(inputStream, outputMessage.getBody());
        inputStream.close();
    }           
}
```